# TypeError: body is not iterable - RabbitMQ, Celery worker NodeJs,

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, pika

I have a system that writes to RabbitMQ using `Pika` (python). The content is a JSON object which includes a file url of a CSV file that needs processing in the background. In another instance, I have a NodeJs client, that listens to queue and creates tasks that would eventually process it in place or call another NodeJs program with url as a parameter.
For this I'm using [this](https://github.com/actumn/celery.node) `celery.node` library. The problem is with the worker side, I can publish and listen for queue, but when creating tasks `TypeError: body is not iterable` keeps showing.

This is my worker code:

```js
const celery = require('celery-node');

const rabbitmq_broker = `amqp://${RABBITMQ_USER}:${RABBITMQ_PASS}@${RABBITMQ_HOST}:${RABBITMQ_PORT}`;

const worker = celery.createWorker(
    rabbitmq_broker,
    rabbitmq_broker,
    'some_queue'
);

worker.register("tasks.some-task", (data) => {
    console.log('data:', data);
    return data;
});

worker.start()
```

I have opened an issue at this github repo, however, I haven't received any feedback.
Any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The issue was caused because I was listening on `some_queue` instead of the main RabbiMQ broker where the client was publishing Celery tasks. Removing it solved the problem.